# Как заставить потоки ожидать триггера для продолжения выполнения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, семафоры

Есть множество потоков `T1`, ..., `Tn`. Все они выполняют функцию `F`, состоящую из инструкций `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. Как реализовать условие:

> Потоки должны ожидать после выполнения инструкции `f2` до тех пор, пока каждый поток не выполнит инструкцию `f2`.

Т.е. условие **все потоки выполнили f2** должно разрешить каждому потоку выполняться дальше. Как это сделать?

---

На конкретном примере:

```py
import threading
import random
import time


THREAD_COUNT = 5


def thread_func():
    str_to_print = f"{threading.current_thread()} {random.random()}"
    time.sleep(random.random() * 2)
    # Ждать, пока все потоки дойдут до сюда
    print(str_to_print)


def main():
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=thread_func) for _ in range(THREAD_COUNT)]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Видно, вы не знаете о существовании замочков? Я говорю о threading.(R)Lock'ах. Почитайте статьи о синхронизации потоков.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на синхронизацию потоков. `threading.Barrier` как раз то, что мне надо.